# Proper way to interact with ThrownExceptions from the view in RxUi 7

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, system.reactive, reactiveui

I´m trying to understand how to use `Interaction<TInput, TOutput>` in RxUi 7 to show a confirmation alert. After reading the [docs](http://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/interactions/index.html) I came up with this:

**ViewModel**

```
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> Save { get; }
public Interaction<Exception, bool> ConfirmError;

Save
    .ThrownExceptions
    .Subscribe(ex => ConfirmError
                       .Handle(ex)
                       .Where(retry => retry == true)
                       .SelectMany(_ => Save.Execute(Unit.Default))
                       .Subscribe()
                       .AddTo(disposables))
    .AddTo(disposables);
```

**View**

```
this
    .ViewModel
    .ConfirmError
    .RegisterHandler(async interaction =>
    {
        var retry = await DisplayAlert("Confirm", 
                                       $"Something went wrong: {interaction.Input.Message}. Do you want to retry?", 
                                       "Yes", 
                                       "No");
        interaction.SetOutput(retry);
    })
    .AddTo(disposables);
```

My code is working but I´m not sure if I´m executing the command correctly when confirmation is done. I also think it´s way too much code for a simple alert box and I´m looking for a proper way to do it.
How could this be simplified?

Second question would be:

If I need to handle more than one `Exception` type (ie: service error, connection error), where is the right place to check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your code is mostly ok, except one thing - you are doing a `Subscribe` call inside another `Subscribe`, which IMO is a code smell. To get rid of it, you could write something like this:

```
Save
    .ThrownExceptions
    .SelectMany(ConfirmError.Handle)
    .Where(retry => retry == true)
    .SelectMany(_ => Save.Execute(Unit.Default))
    .Subscribe()
    .AddTo(disposables);
```

This could be made slightly more readable (?) by using [`InvokeCommand`](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/rxui7-master/src/ReactiveUI/ReactiveCommand.cs#L1041:L1050) helper:

```
Save
    .ThrownExceptions
    .SelectMany(ConfirmError.Handle)
    .Where(retry => retry == true)
    .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
    .InvokeCommant(Save)
    .AddTo(disposables);
```

N.B. I haven't played much with RxUI 7.0, so I'm changing the stream to one containing units is a wild guess.

> I also think it´s way too much code for a simple alert box

Well, this is an alert box *and* a retry logic. I'm not sure if you can have it in RxUI much simpler than that.

> If I need to handle more than one Exception type (ie: service error, connection error), where is the right place to check it?

Personally, I would not think about *exception* types, but about the ways you want to interact with an actual user. After all, you probably don't want to show him the stack trace.

One way to do that would be to have separate `Interactions` for different types of, well, interaction with the user (`MessageInteraction`, `YesNoInteraction` etc), which would allow you to differentiate between e.g. actions requiring user input and toast messages. Another way to go would be to define all possible problems as an enum (`ConnectionTimeout`, `ServiceError` etc.) and possible resolutions as another one (`Retry`, `Abort`, ...) and then have a single `Interaction<ProblemEnum, ResolutionEnum>` in your ViewModel. That way, the code handling the errors will be stored in one place. The downside of this approach would be that the handling logic would be in the View, so it would be much harder to test.

I suggest you try out and report back how my ideas work out in practice :)

Comment: That works beautifully. 
I totally misunderstood how `SelectMany` works. `InvokeCommand` makes total sense as well. About sending exception objects to view you are right, it does not make sense at all. En enum or something similar could be better.